# How to run location updates in background continuously by using swift 4 in IOS11

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing a project about continuous background location update, my final goal is to make the app stay forever (unless user kills it).But I can only run 30 hours and I don't know why. Originally, I did not modify distanceFilter, it could only stay 26 hours. I checked the documentation about app's five states, I'm not sure in what kind of condition the app will move from background to suspended.

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager!.delegate = self
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    }
    locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager!.distanceFilter = 100
```

I'm using standard location update ( startUpdatingLocation() ), not significant location change. Also, I use firebase to be my backend, all location data will be updated to there.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let now = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    let currentTime = dateFormatter.string(from: now)

    if locations.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    let lastloc = locations.last
    if lastloc == nil {
        return
    }

    let lat = String(lastloc!.coordinate.latitude)
    let lng = String(lastloc!.coordinate.longitude)

    let data = ["Lat": lat, "Lng": lng]

    ref.child("GPS").child(userID!).child(String(testCount)+"-"+currentTime).setValue(data)

    testCount = testCount + 1
}
```

I suppose firebase does not have auto-logout function.
Any suggestion would be appreciable, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not beeing killed due to memory allocation?

Comment: i think that's the reason, but is it possible to prevent this problem? I've tried to use significant location change to wake the app again but user information is deleted, which means app cannot update data to Firebase. Therefore, i change my way back to standard one.